# How to transfer data from Internet Explorer site to Excel? Get Element by ID (ng-content)

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, getelementbyid, ng-content

I'm developing a macro in Excel (VBA) to load information from an Excel spreadsheet to Internet Explorer (URL: https://www.tarifasdepedagios.com.br/tarifas/inicial), to click on calculate button and, after, to get results from IE to the Excel spreadsheet.

How do I transfer result data from Internet Explorer to Excel?

**Example:**

Input Data:

- Origin: São Paulo, SP, Brazil
- Destination: Rio de Janeiro, RJ, Brazil

Results:

- Distance: 435,06 km (ID in the HTML code: "mat-input-3")
- Toll: R$59,70 (ID on the HTML code: "mat-input-5")

Is it possible to get these results by `getElementsbyID` in VBA?

Error is related to "ng-content" in the HTML code?

Link HTML Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWoEW.png

VBA Code is below:

```
Sub Pesquisa_Informações_Rota_TarifasdePedagios()

  Dim IE As InternetExplorer, CidadeOrig As String, sng As Date
  Dim LR As Long, Contador As Long, CidadeDest As String

  Dim RS_litro As String
  Dim km_litro As String
  Dim Percentual As Single

  'Limpa os resultados da última pesquisa realizada

  Sheets("tarifasdepedagios.com.br").Select
  Range("C5:F5").Select
  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range("A1").Select

  'Identifica a última célula ativa da lista
  Sheets("tarifasdepedagios.com.br").Select
  LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  'Cria um objeto Internet Explorer
  Set IE = New InternetExplorer

  'Torna o objeto visível
  IE.Visible = True 'True ou False

  'Faz um loop por todas as linhas da planilha
   For Contador = 5 To LR

     'Navega ao site do Tarifas de Pedagios
     IE.Navigate "https://www.tarifasdepedagios.com.br/tarifas/inicial"

    'Identifica se a página já foi totalmente carregada
     While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     Wend
     sng = Timer
     Do While sng + 3 > Timer
     Loop

     'Carrega os dados de cidade de origem e destino que serão preenchidos na página
     RS_litro = Range("B1").Value
     km_litro = Range("B2").Value
     CidadeOrig = Range("A" & Contador).Value
     CidadeDest = Range("B" & Contador).Value

     'Carrega os dados de cidade de origem e destino na página e submente os dados do formulário
     IE.document.all.Item("mat-input-9").Click
     IE.document.all("mat-input-9").Value = CidadeOrig
     IE.document.all.Item("mat-input-10").Click
     IE.document.all("mat-input-10").Value = CidadeDest
     IE.document.all("mat-input-0").Value = RS_litro
     IE.document.all("mat-input-1").Value = km_litro
     IE.document.all.Item("botaoRoteirizar").Click

    'Identifica se a página já foi totalmente carregada
     While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     Wend
     sng = Timer
     Do While sng + 3 > Timer
     Loop

    'Retorna os valores de distância, tempo, pedágio e combustível nas colunas 'C', 'D', 'E' e 'F'
    Cells(Contador, 3) = IE.document.getElementsById("mat-input-3")(0).Value <- ERROR HERE (Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method)
    Cells(Contador, 4) = IE.document.getElementsById("mat-input-4")(0).Value
    Cells(Contador, 5) = IE.document.getElementsById("mat-input-6")(0).Value
    Cells(Contador, 6) = IE.document.getElementsById("mat-input-5")(0).Value

    Percentual = (Contador - 4) / (LR - 4)

    AtualizaBarra Percentual

    Next Contador

    IE.Quit

    frmProcesso.Hide

    MsgBox "Olá, " & Application.UserName & "!" + vbCrLf + "Pesquisa finalizada!"

End Sub
```

Comment: `getElementsById` is not an existing method: it's `getElementById` and it only returns a single element so you don't need the `(0)`

Answer (score 0):

The function should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`. It gets a particular element in HTML and you could refer to [this link](https://techinterviewpuzzles.appspot.com/articles/VbScript/getElementById-in-vbscript-with-example) for the usage.

You should modify your code like this from the error line:

```
'Retorna os valores de distancia, tempo, pedágio e combustível nas colunas 'C', 'D', 'E' e 'F'
    Cells(Contador, 3) = IE.document.getElementById("mat-input-3").Value
    Cells(Contador, 4) = IE.document.getElementById("mat-input-4").Value
    Cells(Contador, 5) = IE.document.getElementById("mat-input-6").Value
    Cells(Contador, 6) = IE.document.getElementById("mat-input-5").Value
```